# Why does momentJS convert "02-31-2015" into "03 March 2015"

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My user can change the url with a date.

When I enter the url`s date params to 2015-02-31 and I create a momentJS object of it I get a date like 03 March 2015.

Even when I consider that the date 2015-02-31 and its month '02' is actually the third month for javascript then the date after creation should be 31 March 2015 and not 03 March 2015

So why the wrong date?

[image]

Comment: Because there is no 31th day of February.  The 31st day after the beginning of February is the 3rd of March (depends on year leapness). (Try entering the fiftieth of February, and see if it lands mid-April).

Comment: maybe it's 0 based index?  Iserni is probably correct though

Comment: @user2879041: it's only JS months that are zero-based. days/years are 1-based.

Comment: Parsing an invalid date string [should return *NaN*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4).

Comment: @RobG OP is using Moment.js, which extracts the date parts and passes them to the Date constructor -- `new Date(2015, 1, 31)` => Tue Mar 03 2015

Comment: @FabrícioMatté—well aware of that, hence use of "should". No doubt moment.js will become compliant at some future date. Or not. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There is only 28 days in February.
When you enter 2015-02-31 it is 3 days (31-28) to the next month, which is March,
That is why the date is 3 March 2015

Answer (score 2):

This is called "lenient" date parsing provided by JavaScript. You cannot easily disable it, however, there are some approaches, e.g. http://www.gitshah.com/2010/08/how-to-accept-only-strict-dates-using.html

Comment: There is no "lenient parsing" in ES5. *Date.parse* will return *NaN* for an invalid date in compliant implementations (see [*ECMA-262 §11.1.4*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4), moment.js is not compliant.

Comment: @RobG The paragraph seems about arrays, not dates. There is §15.9.4.2 and it says "the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats." which sounds like it could allow lenient

Comment: Yes, sorry, wrong reference, is should have been §15.9.4.2 as you point out. Implementations can fall back to whatever they like to parse the string, however: "*Unrecognisable Strings or **dates containing illegal element values in the format String** shall cause Date.parse to return NaN*". That's pretty explicit—invalid date strings must return *NaN* and as far as I know, all those in current use do (for the string formats that they parse).

Comment: @RobG Probably I am missing something, but It doesn't say exactly what is "illegal". I assume it is for a case like `Date.parse("hello world")`, when the string is completely nonsensical, but if it could parse it anyhow, it tries the best, i.e. uses "implementation-specific heuristics".

Comment: Sure, maybe I was subconsciously applying the stricter standard in [*§15.9.1.15*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15): *Illegal values (out-of-bounds as well as syntax errors) in a format string means that the format string is not a valid instance of this format*. I suspect the "leniency" is historical since it doesn't make sense for an invalid string to produce a valid date, e.g. `new Date('02-31-2015')` returns *NaN* in Safari, Omniweb and Firefox but a Date in Chrome.

Comment: @RobG Huh, thanks. Nice to know that it is browser-specific... as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my problem:

Using one of the possible date strings on the momentJS site will still create the date as 3rd march 2015 but internally due to _i "2015 2 31" the isValid returns false just what I needed!

[image]